# wget analysis file sizes

Tags: linux, bash, networking, putty

When downloading different file sizes from the same host I observe the tendency of small files being downloaded slower than big files.

Say 100 kb file would have speed around 300 kb/sec

And 1 mb file for the same host has a speed around 1.2 mb/sec.

What are the factors affecting the speed for the same host?

Thanks,

Comment: I think the limitation is due to the TCP model itself -- where packets incrementally speed up until tit determines it reached a maximum speed. With a small file, it doesn't have time to reach maximum speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TCP slow-start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-start) makes a huge difference for short-lived requests.  If you are using modern Linux, you can tune `initcwnd` and see if that makes a difference.